# SSIS package to run under windows authentication

Tags: authentication, ssis

I have some SSIS packages deployed on server with windows authentication (my user account) using protection level as ServerStorage. Also SQL admin has created jobs to run these packages, admin account is the owner of all the jobs. The jobs are running fine till date but now since my work is over my account will be deleted from AD and I am not sure whether the packages will work or not thru jobs.
It would be great if you can help me understanding the impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really hard to know without knowing the full scope of what your packages do.

If the admin account has rights to everything your account does, then it probably will be OK.

However, if the packages access files on a network share and the SQL admin account is a local account - you'll have problems.

If the package does anything with linked servers and the account is not able to get to linked server - you'll have problems.

Comment: Admin account is in same domain and not a local account. I believe that account has all rights what my account has. More precisely can SSIS package be run by anyone who has same rights as who deployed it even though the user's account is deleted?

Comment: @Pramodtech If they have the same rights to all the same things, and the package uses Windows authentication for its SQL Server connections, then the account is used for everything - file, database connection etc - and yes, it will be the same as if the package never even knew about your account, because no account information is stored in the package.

Comment: @Pramodtech This is why typically we don't save even encrypted (non-WIndows authentication) information in the package - anything like SQL Server connection strings with SQL Server userid/password is all done with external configuration, not in the package.